# die Function Not Triggering

Tags: php, die

In the following code, the die() function should execute since the URL I pass to  simplexml_load_file() is bad. simplexml_load_file() returns FALSE, which should trigger die():

```
$url = 'http://www.badurl.com';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Error: Can\'t create the object.');
```

How come instead I'm getting the following error message?

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://www.badurl.com): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found in /var/www/badurl.com on line 16

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://www.badurl.com" in /var/www/badurl.com on line 16
Error: Can't create the object.
```

Comment: You can use the `@` to silence the warning. Or even better, you can simply set `display_errors` to `off`. The `die` IS triggered correctly.

Comment: Can you define "bad"? Just because it may not load (if what you used is the actual domain), doesn't mean it's "bad". Whois result: *"\*badurl.com is already registered\*"*. Which didn't load for me, or is taking a long time to load for some unknown reason(s).

Comment: But it did get triggered, didn't it? I see `Error: Can't create the object.` in your output.

Comment: In this case, bad as in it doesn't exist.

Comment: Federkun, you have the answer. I just needed to suppress the error. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@` operator if you want silence the warning, or disable `display_errors`.

```
$xml = @simplexml_load_file($url) or die('Error: Can\'t create the object.');
```

`simplexml_load_file` returns `false` with or without the warning, and `die` is executed anyway.